# Fix "This file is not commonly downloaded" warning - Firefox only

Tags: amazon-web-services, firefox, amazon-s3, http-headers, zip

I run a website ([www.pixelscrapper.com](https://www.pixelscrapper.com)) that serves file downloads of images, and zipped collections of images (which are zip files containing multiple imags, psds, vectors, etc.) **These files are hosted on Amazon S3, and served via download urls generated by aws sdk for php (v1)**.

Just recently, users trying to download our zip files using Firefox have started getting "This file is not commonly downloaded" warnings (*after the download finishes*), which forces them to override the warning before accessing the file via the Firefox download manager. Naturally, this kind of warning causes concern for our users.

[image: not commonly downloaded warning]

**This warning shows up IN FIREFOX ONLY**--Chrome, Edge, and Internet Explorer show no warnings when downloading and opening our zip files. The warning also only seems to show up for (surprise, surprise) files that have been more recently added to the site, and have relatively few total downloads--but many of our files never receive large numbers of downloads, so this warning has the potential to plague many of our files indefinitely.

**My question is: is there anything I can do to prevent this warning?** By adjusting headers, signing files in some way, etc.? (From what I understand, Chrome and Edge also have "uncommon file" warning, but they don't seem to be concerned with our files--why is this warning only firing in Firefox?) I've searched around on Stack Overflow and elsewhere, but most of the questions I've seen about "uncommon download" warnings are targeted at Chrome or Internet Explorer, and I can't seem to find any Firefox-specific information about this warning.

**Here's a sample file download url (generated by aws sdk) that is causing warnings:**

```
https://pixelscrapper-user-content.s3.amazonaws.com/template-attachment/user-2/node-13574/paper-037-template-polka-dots.zip?response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%22ps_marisa-lerin_13574_paper-037-template-polka-dots_cu.zip%22&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIWM7MZMHRPA6FHEA&Expires=1495386939&Signature=HDmwRFPX81CIVrQgu1BkEyR9iRQ%3D
```

Here's an inspection of headers in Firefox:

[image: file headers]

---

**UPDATE:**

The issue here is not the nasty-looking url generated by the aws sdk: I checked downloading the same zip file (containing one jpg, one psd) from the following "clean" url, and it still gives the warning: http://pixelscrapper-misc-files.s3.amazonaws.com/ps_marisa-lerin_13574_paper-037-template-polka-dots_cu.zip

Comment: I don't see such warning with ff  `53.0 (64-bit)` stable. Which version are you using?

Comment: This might help: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-does-phishing-and-malware-protection-work#w_iaove-confirmed-that-my-site-is-safe-how-do-i-get-it-removed-from-the-lists

Comment: @PedroLobito I am getting the warning in 53.0, both 32-bit and 64-bit. Note that the warning only shows up AFTER the download is complete, when attempting to access the file through the Firefox download manager. See screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/rSPPZqx.png . Can you confirm?

Comment: @heylookltsme Thanks for the links, but I don't think that these particular links will help, since our files are not receiving malware warnings: only the "uncommon file" warnings, and only in Firefox.

Comment: its due to the messed up link structure your dl is using, god i hate aws lol. If you can make the url cleaner, without all the added garbage "?response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%22ps_marisa-lerin_13574_paper-037-template-polka-dots_cu.zip%22&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIWM7MZMHRPA6FHEA&Expires=1495386939&Signature=HDmwRFPX81CIVrQgu1BkEyR9iRQ%3D" 

it will remove that warning

Comment: @ATechGuy Thank you for the input. That strikes me as a reasonable thought, but it turns out to be incorrect. I tried downloading the same zip file from S3 via the following "clean" url, and it still produced the same warning: http://pixelscrapper-misc-files.s3.amazonaws.com/ps_marisa-lerin_13574_paper-037-template-polka-dots_cu.zip

Comment: hmmm that is odd, that should have taken care of it. i also notice i am blind, i see you have a psd file in there, that may be it, for kicks, id try zipping that up inside the zip or remove the psd file just to see if you get the warning.

Comment: I have got the same problem. Any updates on this issue?

Comment: I got the same problem, using a standard linux server with normal domain and SSL. It is a PHP package. I first removed the PSD file, as ATechGuy suggested, then the JS files, but even when I'm only left with PHP, JSON, TXT and some normal web image files, it still says my ZIP file definately contains a virus (that's how people read this warning).

Answer (score -1):

Check the settings under menu path Tools->Options->Security. You may need to uncheck the options under the "General" section of that dialogue box. Simply unchecking "Warn me about unwanted and uncommon software" resolves this.

No need to change other settings. I hope it helps.

Also see: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-does-phishing-and-malware-protection-work

Comment: The OP cannot ask every possible user of his site to change those settings.  He's trying to remove it for all, not just for himself.